# Django Channels chat application doesn't open thread if the user is same as the logged in admin

Tags: django, django-channels

I am new to Django channels and I am following this tutorial on youtube

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVH05S1qab8

All the setup is working great, but now I have been bowled by a conflict in the video and the shared git hub code. In the video if you exactly freez on 47:44 it will show you a screen where 2 browser windows are open with the following urls,

> 127.0.0.1:8000/messages/jmitchell3/
>   127.0.0.1:8000/messages/cfe/

Here note that cfe is the user logged into the django admin.

Now the model manager code says the following,

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username

        if username == other_username:
            return None, False

        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)

        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()

        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user, 
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False
```

The view uses the method in the above manager like so,

```
def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        print(other_username)
        print(self.request.user)
        obj, created = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```

If you notice in the ThreadManager, get_or_new returns "none, false" if the user name in the url and the logged in user are the same. Then how can it open up on the browser? I might be missing a very simple or silly point but please help, I've been wracking my brain on this for quiet some time.

Comment: on the video the second browser windows is in the incognito mode, did you do the same?

Comment: After you pointed it out, I tried the incognito mode, still no luck. As incognito doesn't keep the cookies, I have to login again as the admin and then when I try to go to .../messages/cfe its shows the page not found 404 error.

Comment: Hi Bear Brown it was indeed the incognito that did it. Was dumb of me. I just had to launch an incognito window , login as a different user and browse to .../messages/cfe in the same window. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: glad you find the solution